# Can't delete an AWS account within an AWS organization after using a username@example.com for the account owner's email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

today I am trying to familiarize myself with the AWS Organizations service. The goal is to distribute AWS resources across a user base within an application and then obtain the billing information per individual. I figured I would create an AWS account for each user within one centralized AWS org and then use a service like AWS cost explorer to get the billing data at an account level (or something I still have to research the best option to grab the billing data) so i know how much to charge my users. The goal was to create an organization and then an account within that org, simple right?

So here is the "create an AWS account" page on the web console.

[image]

So i originally tried to create an account with my personal AWS account's email address. I was given an error "EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS"

This is because I have already registered my personal email as an AWS account. Well obviously this will be a problem and not the solution I am looking for since some of the users will have and will need to at some point create their own AWS account tied to their own email address. So obvisouly this wouldn't be possible.

So then I thought hey maybe I can create domain name emails like username@mydomain.com for each user! I didn't have a domain ready to go right then and there, to be honest i didn't even know if this domain name email would require authentication before creation or not. So i thought I would try using an internet namespace like username@example.com to find out... and nope it didn't! The account was created and added to my companys AWS organization with no email verification. Okay cool. so then I immediately went to delete the test account and am seeing this error error

[image]

As you can see it says the account can't be removed because the member account must be configured with a valid payment method such as a credit card.... uhhh...

Obviously this is not possible because i don't have access to any *@example.com email address to verify an AWS account but I guess i just registered one on accident and now I am being told I need to login to that account and verify a credit card just to delete it and remove it from the organization?

Furthermore I have been made aware that I can't delete the organization entity until all the accounts have been removed. Oh boy...

If anyone has any experience to share on this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Contact AWS (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/)).

Comment: I contacted AWS and they told me what I already stated. The report was that there was nothing I could do besides log into that account and add a valid card in order for me to remove it. The support suggested I leave the account within the organization as a test account (didn't think I had much choice on that one). I am not sure what this means for me when I go and close this AWS root account since there is a resource attached to it that I can't get rid of.

Comment: Presumably you created the member account through the organization management (root) account and so an IAM role named OrganizationAccountAccessRole was created in the member account and you can assume this role from an IAM principal in the management account. See [Accessing a member account that has a management account access role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html#orgs_manage_accounts_access-cross-account-role).